# Manual Maximum-Likelihood Estimation of an AR-Model in R

Tags: r, estimation

I am trying to estimate a simple AR(1) model in R of the form **y[t] = alpha + beta * y[t-1] + u[t]**  with u[t] being normally distributed with mean zero and standard deviation sigma.

I have simulated an AR(1) model with **alpha = 10** and **beta = 0.1**:

```
library(stats)
data<-arima.sim(n=1000,list(ar=0.1),mean=10)
```

First check: OLS yields the following results:

```
lm(data~c(NA,data[1:length(data)-1]))

Call:
lm(formula = data ~ c(NA, data[1:length(data) - 1]))

Coefficients:
                (Intercept)  c(NA, data[1:length(data) - 1])  
                   10.02253                          0.09669
```

But my goal is to estimate the coefficients with ML. My negative log-likelihood function is:

```
logl<-function(sigma,alpha,beta){
-sum(log((1/(sqrt(2*pi)*sigma)) * exp(-((data-alpha-beta*c(NA,data[1:length(data)-1]))^2)/(2*sigma^2))))
}
```

that is, the sum of all log-single observation normal distributions, that are transformed by u[t] = y[t] - alpha - beta*y[t-1]. The lag has been created (just like in the OLS estimation above) by c(NA,data[1:length(data)-1]).

When I try to put it at work I get the following error:

```
library(stats4)
mle(logl,start=list(sigma=1,alpha=5,beta=0.05),method="L-BFGS-B")
Error in optim(start, f, method = method, hessian = TRUE, ...) : 
L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'
```

My log-likelihood function must be correct, when I try to estimate a linear model of the form **y[t] = alpha + beta * x[t] + u[t]** it works perfectly.

I just do not see how my initial values lead to a non-finite result? Trying any other initial values does not solve the problem.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: I find it annoying when seeing code that obviously uses functions from non-standard packages is posted without including the `library` calls that would identify and load the function. (I also don't see recognition in your code of the fact that lagged variables have NA's.)

Comment: @DWin , I think it's just `stats4::mle`, so `library(stats4)` should do it. At least this is a base package ...

Comment: When I did ?mle I got a "No documentation for ‘mle’" message. So maybe it's like `grid` and not routinely loaded despite being recommended.

Comment: Yes, you do need `library(stats4)`.  I haven't looked carefully, but I strongly suspect that the primary issue is the `NA` values in the lagged variables -- this would make the ML `NA`.  Rule #1: always check by evaluating your log-likelihood function at any proposed initial values to make sure the results make sense!

Comment: Sorry that I did not include all the "library" commands and the data. Now everything is there :) I also do believe that the error must come from the fact that there is a NA value in the data, even though to me it is strange to receive "this" message. Does anyone please know how I overcome the problem with the first value being NA? How do I tell R to start with the second observation? Thank you.

Comment: you need something like `dat <- data.frame(y=y[-1],x=x[-1],xlag1=x[-length(x)])` (or you can use `tail()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me -- basically what you've done but leaving out the first element of the response, since we can't predict it with an AR model anyway.

Simulate:

```
library(stats)
set.seed(101)
data <- arima.sim(n=1000,list(ar=0.1),mean=10)
```

Negative log-likelihood:

```
logl <- function(sigma,alpha,beta) {
   -sum(dnorm(data[-1],alpha+beta*data[1:length(data)-1],sigma,log=TRUE))
}
```

Fit:

```
library(stats4)
mle(logl,start=list(sigma=1,alpha=5,beta=0.05),method="L-BFGS-B")
## Call:
## mle(minuslogl = logl, start = list(sigma = 1, alpha = 5, beta = 0.05), 
##     method = "L-BFGS-B")
## 
## Coefficients:
##  0.96150573 10.02658632  0.09437847
```

Alternatively:

```
df <- data.frame(y=data[-1],ylag1=head(data,-1))
library(bbmle)
mle2(y~dnorm(alpha+beta*ylag1,sigma),
     start=list(sigma=1,alpha=5,beta=0.05),
     data=df,method="L-BFGS-B")
```

Comment: Smooth solution! Thank you for your time!