# Maximum Likelihood estimate of ARIMA-not matching the value computed using arima()

Tags: r, statistics

I am new to r. I am using the optim function to obtain the maximum likelihood estimate of an arima function assuming residuals are normally distributed. I have differenced the data once to make it stationary. I have written the following to calculate the likelihood:-

```
kings <- scan("http://robjhyndman.com/tsdldata/misc/kings.dat",skip=3)

arima1<-function(a=length(kings))
{e<-array(0,dim=a-2);
e[1:2]=0
y=diff(kings)



likelihood<-function(AR,e,y)
{for(i in 3:41)
{e[i]<-sum(y[i],-AR[1],-(AR[2]*y[i-1]),-(AR[3]*y[i-2]),-(AR[4]*e[i-1]),-(AR[5]*e[i-2]))
}
-sum(-(a-1)*(log(AR[6]*(2*22/7)^.5)),-(sum(e^2)/(2*(AR[6])^2)))
}

optim(par<-c(0,0,1,0,1,14),likelihood,y=y,e=e,control=list(maxit=1000))

}
arima1()
```

However the parameters obtained by using the function arima(y,order<-c(2,0,2)) are different 
from that obtained from the code above. Could you identify the problem in the logic of the code?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you supposed to make this function yourself?  There are packages in R that do MLE for ARIMA models, such as `TSA` (time series analysis).

Comment: A friend of mine advised me to perform the function manually first without adopting the automated function. He said it was the best way to learn the how the system works.

Answer (score 1):

Can't make sense of your log function. Additionally, I think you are expecting too much from the arima and optim functions. Here are a few comments:

1. For your purposes (learning) I would generate a series using the `arima.sim` function. This will allow you to know the values that `optim` and `arima` are supposed to give.
2. The `arima` function gets it wrong sometimes. In two consecutive runs this is what the results where in my computer:

   > y = arima.sim(n=1000,list(ar=c(0.6, -0.2), ma=c(-0.7, 0.5)),mean=0.3)
   >   arima(y,order=c(2,0,2))$coef
   >   ar1:**0.3489**  ar2:**0.1060**  ma1:**-0.4318**  ma2:**0.1887** intercept:**0.4919**
   >
   > y = arima.sim(n=1000,list(ar=c(0.6, -0.2), ma=c(-0.7, 0.5)),mean=0.3)
   >   arima(y,order=c(2,0,2))$coef
   >   ar1:**0.6100** ar2:**-0.1672** ma1:**-0.6663**  ma2:**0.4816**  intercept:**0.4199**

Notice that the ar2 for the first result doesn't even have the same sign and is crappy all around. But the second is a pretty nice fit. Same simulation function parameters, but different results.

3. Notice that the fewer values you have on the time series, the harder it is to get accurate results. Here are some runs on my computer.

   > y = arima.sim(n=42,list(ar=c(0.6, -0.2), ma=c(-0.7, 0.5)),mean=0.3)
   >   arima(y,order=c(2,0,2))$coef
   >   ar1:**-1.1102** ar2:**-0.4528**  ma1:**1.2052**  ma2:**0.9999**  intercept:**0.2353260**
   >   y = arima.sim(n=42,list(ar=c(0.6, -0.2), ma=c(-0.7, 0.5)),mean=0.3)
   >   arima(y,order=c(2,0,2))$coef
   >   ar1:**0.8623** ar2:**-0.3935** ma1:-1.0745  ma2:**0.9999**  intercept:**0.4109**
   >   y = arima.sim(n=42,list(ar=c(0.6, -0.2), ma=c(-0.7, 0.5)),mean=0.3)
   >   arima(y,order=c(2,0,2))$coef
   >   ar1:**-0.2749**  ar2:**0.4170** ma1:**-0.0078** ma2:**-0.0586**  intercept:**0.3737**

All of these results are pretty sucky.

4.I found your code a bit hard to read/understand. Here is what I ran on my machine (With results).

```
library(stats4)

kings <- scan("http://robjhyndman.com/tsdldata/misc/kings.dat",skip=3)
y = diff(kings)
Y_0 = y[c(-1,-2)] # this is y(t)
Y_1 = y[c(-1,-length(y))] # this is y(t-1)
Y_2 = y[1:(length(y)-2)] # this is y(t-2)

logARMA22 <- function ( ar1=0.1, ar2=-0.2, ma1=-0.7, ma2=0.1, alpha=0.42, sigma=14)
{
    E_0 = array(0, dim=length(Y_0))
    E_1 = array(0, dim=length(Y_0))
    E_2 = array(0, dim=length(Y_0))

    for ( i in 1:length(E_0) )
    {   
        E_0[i] = Y_0[i] - ar1*Y_1[i] - ar2*Y_2[i]
                 - ma1*E_1[i] - ma2*E_2[i] - alpha
        if ( (i+1) <= length(E_1) )
            E_1 [i+1] = E_0[i]
        if ( (i+2) <= length(E_2) )
            E_2 [i+2] = E_0[i]
    }   

    # e^2
    E2 = (Y_0-alpha-ar1*Y_1-ar2*Y_2-ma1*E_1-ma2*E_2)^2
    res = suppressWarnings( - sum(log( (1/(sqrt(2*pi)*sigma)) * exp(-(E2)/(2*sigma^2)))) )
    return(res)
}

print(arima(y, order=c(2,0,2))$coef)
print(mle(logARMA22))

#Read 42 items
#         ar1          ar2          ma1          ma2    intercept 
# 0.087452103 -0.122367077 -0.740473745  0.006492026  0.372799202 
#
#Call:
#mle(minuslogl = logARMA22)
#
#Coefficients:
#        ar1         ar2         ma1         ma2       alpha       sigma 
#-0.07772158 -0.48516681 -0.50804965  0.03678942  0.10385160 15.33830148
```

Note that mle is just a front end for optim (so you are actually calling optim here). The results are not equal probably due to the size of the sample. The log-likelihood function in this case was taken from "Henrik Madsen, 2008, Time Series Analysis. equation 6.72 (page 167)". Also [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18685629/manual-maximum-likelihood-estimation-of-an-ar-model-in-r) will probably be helpful as well.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The arima() function does not use the maximum likelihood method to fit the model.

> The exact likelihood is computed via a state-space representation of the ARIMA process, and the innovations and their variance found by a Kalman filter.